# How can I select an element's content and copy it to clipboard?

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey, userscripts, clipboarddata

I want to be able to click on certain text on specific sites and have it selected **and** copied to keyboard. So far I use something like this to select the text within specific classes using Stylus.

```css
.classname {
    user-select: all;
}
```

How can I have it copied to keyboard too? Trying this for [IATE](https://iate.europa.eu/search/byUrl?term=Durststreik&sl=de) did work on selecting the string but did not work on copying (clicking on any of the translations there).

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Iate select
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        https://iate.europa.eu/*
// @icon         data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

  let style = document.createElement('style');
  style.innerHTML = 'app-iate-search-term-refine{ user-select: all !important; }';

  document.body.appendChild(style);

const element = document.querySelector('app-iate-search-term-refine');

element.addEventListener('click', () => {
const text = element.textContent;

    GM_setClipboard(text);
});
})();
```

Comment: try to change the grant statement to: \@grant GM_setClipboard

Comment: Thanks, I tried but nothing changed.

Comment: Note you can also use [`GM_addStyle`](https://www.tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#GM_addStyle) instead of creating and appending a `<style>` element to the body.

Comment: I tried adding `GM_addStyle("app-iate-search-term-refine{ user-select: all !important; }");` but it did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add [`click` event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event) on the element whose text you want to copy, then use [`GM_setClipboard`](https://www.tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#GM_setClipboard). Note that:

- The elements aren't accessible when the DOM is "ready". Therefore, the script below uses [`waitForKeyElements`](https://gist.github.com/BrockA/2625891/), a utility developed by [Brock Adams](https://stackoverflow.com/users/331508/brock-adams).
- There are more elements of type `app-iate-search-term-refine`, you need to query them all, then loop throgh each and add the same event listener.

This example should work:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Iate select
// @version      0.1
// @author       greektranslator
// @match        https://iate.europa.eu/*
// @require      https://gist.githubusercontent.com/BrockA/2625891/raw/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant        GM_setClipboard
// @grant        GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/* globals waitForKeyElements */

(function() {
    'use strict';

    GM_addStyle('app-iate-search-term-refine { user-select: all !important; }');

    waitForKeyElements('app-iate-search-term-refine', addListener, false);

    function addListener() {
        const elements = document.querySelectorAll('app-iate-search-term-refine');

        elements.forEach(element => {
            element.addEventListener('click', () => {
                const text = element.textContent.trim();

                GM_setClipboard(text);
            });
        });
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

This code can be used. It worked for me one day.

```js
element.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const text = element.textContent;

    navigator.clipboard.writeText(text)
    .then(() => {
      // Here you can handle successful copying
    })
    .catch(err => {
      // Here you can handle error (err)
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried to implement but no luck in copying. Please see latest code version on original post.